# If cart button' is clicked from same item then no new row will be added to table view else button is clicked from different items add new row

Tags: swift, uitableview

I want to display table view cellForRow at index path function with the condition 
if Add to Button is clicked from same item from second view controller then row in the third controller(Cart View Controller) will be same
else if Add to Button is clicked for different item then new row will be added in table view

Detail View Controller Code:

```
@IBAction func addToCartTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

     performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToCartView", sender: self)

}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "goToCartView" {

        let desVC = segue.destination as! CartViewController

        desVC.cartImage = imgImage.image!
        desVC.cartImageTitle = lblLabel.text!
    }
```

Cart View Controller Code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ItemsCell", for: <#T##IndexPath#>) as! CartTableViewCell

    cell.imageCell.image = cartImage
    cell.titleCell.text = cartImageTitle
    cell.priceCell.text = cartPrice

    return (cell)
}
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVdsb.png)

Comment: Can you describe the actual scenario in your app to make it more clear?

Comment: Are you working on the tree structure?

Comment: Question not clear. Add the screenshot for better understanding.

Comment: I have added screenshot. I am new to coding. I hope now you can help me.